# Feller property of Ito diffusion

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the following Ito diffusion $X_t$ satisfying

$$dX_t=b(X_t)dt+\sigma(X_t)dB_t,\quad X_0=x,$$

with Lipschitz coefficients $b,\sigma$.

It can be shown that if $g$ is bounded and continuous, then $u(x)=E^x[g(X_t)]$ is continuous. So any Ito diffusion is [Feller continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feller-continuous_process).

However, some books define Feller property to be if  $g$ is continuous and vanishes at infinity, then $u$ is continuous and vanishes at infinity.

It seems that Brownian Motion satisfies this property. Also some literature shows if the associated generator is uniformly elliptic then it has a transition density and $X_t$ has this property.

May I know whether in general $X_t$ satisfying this property?

---

Following Danielsen's suggestion, I formulated the following proof, may you help to verify whether it's correct? In particular, I am not sure whether equation (1) is correct, since those two integrals are not fixed constants as $x\to \infty$.

Fix $g$ be continuous and vanishes at infinity, and $t>0$.

Then as $x\to \infty$, 
$$X^x_t(\omega)=x+\int_0^t b(X_s(\omega))\,ds+\int_0^t \sigma(X_s)\,dB_s(\omega)\to \infty,\tag{1}$$ for almost all $\omega$,

hence $g(X^x_t(\omega))\to 0$ a.s. then by boundedness convergence theorem,

we have $E^x[g(X_t)]=E^0[g(X^x_t)]\to 0$.

So Ito diffusion has the Feller property.

Comment: You're not going to be able to Girsanov away that $\sigma(X_t)$.

Comment: If $g$ is continuous and vanishes at infinity, then $$u(x)=E^x[g(X_t)]=E^0[g(X_t+x)]$$ by the bounded convergence theorem $u(x)\to 0$

Comment: @Danielsen Why $E^x[g(X_t)]=E^0[g(X^x_t)]=E^0[g(X_t+x)]$?

Comment: @JohnZHANG Because $P^x[X_t\in A]=P^0[X_t+x\in A]$.

Comment: @Danielsen Isn't it $P^x[X_t∈A]=P^0[X_t^x\in A]$? What do you mean by $X_t$?

Comment: @JohnZHANG In your notation, it is $X_t^x-x$.

Comment: @Danielsen Sorry I don't understand. So why $g(X_t^x-x+x)\to 0$ almost surely as $x\to \infty$? Are you suggesting as $x\to \infty$, $X_t^x-x$ is fixed (independent of $x$)?

Comment: @JohnZHANG It is the same as what you edited, the only difference is the notation.

Comment: @Danielsen But I think $X_t=X_t^x-x=\int_0^t b(X_s)\,ds+\int_0^t \sigma(X_s)\,dB_s$ is not independent of $X_0=x$, as $x\to \infty$, $X_t$ is also affected.

Comment: @Danielsen: There is no reason to think that $X^x_t =x+X_t$ unless $b$ and $\sigma$ are constant.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Sorry... I thought it is the same as constant coefficient. Ignore my comments.

Comment: @JohnDawkins May I know how to show the decay at infinity if I assume $\sigma$ is a constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $b$ and $\sigma$ are Lipschitz continous functions, then $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has the Feller property, i.e. $x \mapsto \mathbb{E}^x(g(X_t))$ is continuous and vanishing at $\infty$ for any function $g$ which is continuous and vanishing at $\infty$. For a proof see for instance *René Schiling & Lothar Partzsch: Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes*, Corollary 19.27 and 19.31 (2nd edition).

Your proof, however, is not correct. More precisely, equation $(1)$ is not correct, it should read

$$X_t^x(\omega) = x+\int_0^t b(X_s^{\color{red}{x}}(\omega)) \, ds + \int_0^t \sigma(X_s^{\color{red}{x}}) \, dB_s(\omega);$$

in particular the two integrals on the right-hand side depend on $x$, and therefore we cannot simply let $x \to \infty$.

**Remark** $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ does, in general, not satisfy the Feller property if $\sigma$ and $b$ are not (globally) Lipschitz continuous, but only locally Lipschitz continuous. Consider for instance the solution of the differential equation

$$dX_t = - X_t^3 \, dt \qquad X_0 = x$$

which can be calculated explicitly.